# Servicestack IDbConnection injection into static classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, servicestack, inversion-of-control

I am using servicestack 4. How can I inject database connections into static classes?

Pseudo-code:

```
public static class SomeRepository
{
    public static IDbConnection Db { get; set; }

    public static List<SomeEntity> DoSomething()
    {
        return Db.Select<SomeEntity>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a static class in the first place? Make your life much easier and make it an instance class and inject the dependency into its constructor.

Comment: I'm experimenting with servicestack & ormlite. In my previous medium-sized project (Devforce+EF) I had used static repository classes and it worked fine. I guess I'll have to rethink about servicestack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection()`.

```cs
public static class SomeRepository
{
    public static IDbConnection Db = HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection();

    public static List<SomeEntity> DoSomething()
    {
        return Db.Select<SomeEntity>();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Scott! That works! I wish SS had better documentation.